# Validation plugin for required if previous checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

How do I find the previous checkbox to an element using jquery?

I'm writing a custom validation plug-in "cb-required" which acts like "required" if and only if the previous checkbox is checked. The idea is a checkbox followed by one or more dependent text fields and/or selects. I'm not concerned with hiding or disabling the dependent fields in anyway, I just want to enforce "required" if the checkbox is checked.

Right now I'm simply trying to get an alert to pop-up correctly and .prev() is not doing the trick:

```
$.validator.addMethod("cb-required", function(value, element) {
    alert("current="+$(element).attr("name")+" / previous="+$(element).prev(":checkbox").attr("name"));
    return true;
}, "This information is required");
```

The form fields look something like this:

```
<input name="EMVEnabled" type="checkbox" value="1" />EMV enabled<br />
<span style="font-size:0.8em">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>EMV Template</strong>
    <select name="EMVTemplate" size="1" class="cb-required">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">Template 1</option>
        <option value="2">Template 2</option>
    </select><br />
</span>
<br />
<input name="CashAdvance" type="checkbox" value="1" />Cash advance<br />
<br />
<input name="ExpressPay" type="checkbox" value="1" />Express pay<br />
<span style="font-size:0.8em">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Floor Limit Min</strong>
    <input name="ExpressPayFloorMin" type="text" value="" size="12" maxlength="12" class="cb-required numeric" /><br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Floor Limit Max</strong>
    <input name="ExpressPayFloorMax" type="text" value="" size="12" maxlength="12" class="cb-required numeric" /><br />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, your alternate method got me thinking of another way to tackle the problem. In the html I wrapped the checkbox and the dependencies in a div with class="cb-group" attribute. then the following tweak works:

```
$.validator.addMethod("cb-required", function(value, element) {
    alert("current="+$(element).attr("name")+" / previous="+$(element).closest(".cb-group").find(":checkbox").attr("name"));
    return true;
}, "This information is required");
```

Now I can continue and finish with the real logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using your specific example, .prev(":checkbox") isn't working because that method does not move up the DOM tree—it will only look at direct siblings. You want to use .parent().prev(":checkbox") or parent.prevAll(":checkbox") if there is a chance that another DOM element would be between the checkbox and the dependent input's parent.

Alternatively, you may want to look into specifying, in your .validate({}) declaration for the "cb-required" rule, the exact checkbox (by jquery selector string) to use for validation, rather than relying on the structure of the DOM. This would give you the flexibility to place your checkbox anywhere in the DOM relative to the input(s) that depend on its checked state, like so:

```
$form.validate({
    rules: {
        ExpressPayFloorMin: {
            "cb-required": "[name=ExpressPay]"
        }
    }
});
```

Using this method, you would need to add a third argument "param" to your validation function, which would be the selector specified in .validate():

```
$.validator.addMethod("cb-required", function(value, element, param) {
    return $(param).prop("checked") && ($(element).val().length > 0);
}, "This information is required");
```

Comment: I figured that was my problem with using .prev(), I just could not think of a solution using the parent. The alternative method is one I thought of but I was hoping for a more generic solution.